# hivevar ignoring values after the space

Tags: linux, shell, variables, hive, hiveql

I have file format like this (publishfile.txt)

```
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/OMEGA
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample
drwxrwx---+  h655201 supergroup          0  2019-04-24  09:16  /data/xyz/invisible/se/raw_data/sample(1)
```

and want to store the values of filename in a table like OMEGA,sample,sample(1). For this I have used code like this

```
FILE_NAME=$(echo "$line"| awk -F / '{ print $NF }' "$BASE_PATH/publishfile.txt")
echo FILE_NAME
```

Here Output of FILE_NAME IS COMING like -----> `OMEGA  sample  sample(1)`
But when I'am passing this to ---hivevar it takes only the sample(1) value Like in my code

```
beeline -u $HIVEPATH --hivevar namenode=$NAMENODE --hivevar db=$DB_MASTER$COUNTRY$DB_POSTFIX --hivevar dirlocation --hivevar filename= $FILE_NAME --hivevar queue=$QUEUE_NAME--showHeader=false --showWarnings=true $BASE_PATH/TOM/SCRIPT/hql/insert_data.hql
```

BUT HERE **filename** stores only sample(1) which is inserted in the table how can I make sure whole value of vaariable get into **filename** and it store `OMEGA  sample  sample(1)` value in it

Answer (score 1):

Double-quote variables in shell:

```
--hivevar filename="$FILE_NAME"
```

In this case string containing spaces will be passed as a single variable.

Alternatively you can pass it like this: `--hivevar filename=${FILE_NAME}`

Also your `echo` command should be `echo "$FILE_NAME"` not `echo FILE_NAME`

Variable passing demo:

```
var="one two three";
echo "$var"
```

Prints:

```
one two three
```

Pass it to hive:

```
hive -hivevar var="$var"
```

Print in the hive:

```
hive> select '${hivevar:var}';
OK
one two three
```

Comment: @ShivamSharma How the "$line" is calculated? I'd like to reproduce

Comment: $line is just getting value from the variable or well not required though